# How to set proper exposure in Darktable with scene-referred workflow?

Tags: darktable

I don't understand how to set proper exposure in Darktable.

A few aspects of Darktable are opaque to me and contributing to my confusion. Such as, what the histogram actually shows when the Exposure, Filmic RGB and Sigmoid modules can all affect the histogram. I'm guessing it's the final display-output image, but then what's it displaying if I turned off both Sigmoid and Filmic and the dynamic range is not the display but the camera? Does it change from 8-bit display to X-bit camera historigram depend on which modules are enabled? Another one, where is middle gray in the linear vs log histogram in Darktable?

So .. the primary question: If I have an image with a middle gray area, what is the proper way to set exposure in Darktable, scene-referred workflow?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but unless you're specifically aiming for a low-key (dark) or high-key (bright) image, start with adjusting the exposure and black point to minimize the amount of the image that is clipped at either end of the histogram - the histogram curve should just barely touch both ends of the graph. That's a good starting point, but ultimately it just depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve with the image. I usually do that, and then use the Zone System module for further coarse-grained adjustments

Comment: @twalberg Thanks. Sure, make sure there is no clipping. Which of the Exposure, Filmic and Sigmoid modules do you have on/off when you do this? The histogram is different when different modules are enabled. It's the essence of my question, really.

Comment: I rarely use the more advanced modules like Filmic and Sigmoid. My default stack for new images includes White Balance, Exposure, Zone System, Sharpen and Local Contrast, with reasonable default values (also Base Curve, Orientation, Lens Correction and Hot Pixels, but I almost never have to fiddle with those). I only go beyond that default set if I'm trying to achieve something different, or a particular image really needs it...

Comment: Please tell us what you mean when you say *"proper exposure"*. How do you define *"proper exposure"*?